# Making sure database.yml file has proper credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going through a basic rails tutorial and when I try to run my server with "rails s"
I get ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished in my localhost:3000 browser.

I am told in the tutorial to make sure my database.yml has the proper credentials but not
told how to do that. I am using Postgresql. This is what is in my databse.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrubyblog
  username:postgres
  password: theoffice
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrubyblog
  username:postgres
  password: theoffice
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myrubyblog
  username:postgres
  password: theoffice
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just giving us your `database.yml` file isn't going to help much. Habe you installed PostgreSQL? Have you ensured your PostgreSQL server is running? Can you connect directly to the PostgreSQL database on your computer by running `psql -U postgres postgres`?

Answer (score 1):

Try remove lines:

```
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
host: localhost
```

Try start server again
If it still  fails. Make sure you've installed psql correctly

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
> CREATE ROLE "Blou91" PASSWORD 'secret' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;
```

If you get message like 'Sucsses'. Change database.yml to:

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  username: "Blou91"
  password: "secret"

development:
  <<: *common
  database: myrubyblog_development

test:
  <<: *common
  database: myrubyblog_test

production:
  <<: *common
  database: myrubyblog_production
```

Then run under your rails application directory

> $ bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate